# antlr4: Mismatched input on simple grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar

I have a simple grammar that keeps giving me mismatched input on seemingly right inputs. My grammar is as follows

```
root: expression;

expression
  : METRIC comparator RHS
  | expression AND expression
  | expression OR expression
  | LPAREN expression RPAREN
  ;

comparator
  : EQ | GT | GE | LT | LE;

EQ: [eE][qQ];
GE: [gG][eE];
GT: [gG][tT];
LE: [lL][eE];
LT: [lL][tT];

LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';

AND: [aA][nN][dD];
OR: [oO][rR];

WS: [ \t\n\r]+;

METRIC: 'latency' | 'qps';
RHS: 'foobar' | 'foobaz';
```

Why does this grammar give a `mismatched input 'latency'` error when the input is `latency eq foobar`. Surely this follows the first production `METRIC comparator RHS`

Answer (score 0):

The grammar you posted does not produce the error/warning "mismatched input 'latency'". You probably didn't regenerate the lexer- and parser classes if this is the case.

The only problem with the grammar from you question is the fact that for the input `latency eq foobar`, the lexer produces `WS` tokens which your parser does not accept.

You probably want to skip these `WS` tokens in the lexer:

```
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

With that change, your parser will produce the following parse tree for the input `latency eq foobar`:

[image]

Comment: Adding `-> skip;`, I now get the following message.

```extraneous input 'latency' expecting {METRIC, LPAREN} expected```

Comment: I don't know what to tell you: the image of the parse tree I posted is the result of the  grammar from your original question (only with the `-> skip` added). Tested with ANTLR 4.9.1

Comment: If you still get an error (even after regenerating the lexer & parser classes), please edit your original question with a small piece of code that someone else can use to reproduce it.